# Orthogonalize two sets of vectors against one another

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Given two subspaces $U,V\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and orthonomal bases $U = \{u_1,\ldots,u_p\}$ and $V = \{v_1,\ldots, v_q\}$ (wlog $p\geq q$) is there a fast way to compute an orthonormal basis for $U+V$?

The naieve approach is to use Gram-Schmidt to orthogonalize the smaller basis for $V$ against that of $U$. However this does not take advantage of the fact that we know an orthogonal basis for $V$.

I have talked to a couple professors and they weren't familiar with any algorithms for this problem, so if anyone has some resources which might be related I would be interested. Approximation algorithms and heuristics are very welcome too

Some simplifying assumptions we could make are

1. $U \cap V = 0$
2. $p,q \ll n$
3. That we only need to add $k<q$ vectors to $U$ so that $U+\{v_1,\ldots, v_k\}$ is contained in $U+V$

A related question is if there is a way to append some orthonormal vectors to $U$ with no restriction as to how that changes the span of the new set.

Comment: When you wrote that $U\cap V=\emptyset$, did you really mean that?

Comment: I think so. For example of $U = \{ (1,0,0), (0,1,0) \}$ and $V = \{ (1,1,1) \}$.

Comment: But you wrote that $U$ and $V$ are *subspaces*. And for any two subspaces, you always have $0$ in their intersection.

Comment: My mistake, I meant the intersection is trivial. I have edited this now.

Answer (score 0):

Why should there be a faster algorithm?
Take $U$ included in $\mathbb{R}^4$,
$$
U = span( [1, 0, 0, 0]^T, [0, 1, 0, 0]^T)
$$
and
$$ 
V = span([1; 1; 1; 0] / \sqrt{3}, [a; b; 0; 1] / \sqrt{1 + a^2 + b^2})
$$
$a = b = 0$ yields indeed a simplification.
$a = 1, b = -1$ requires an orthogonalization against $U$